# Firebase error this email is already used by another account

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to implement email and password authentication in one of my angular application,

whenever I try to create a new account I get this error,

'Firebase error this email is already used by another account',

event if there is not a single account created in console,

```
  createAccount(data:{email: string, password: string}) {
    return this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
  }
```

This was my authentication service implementation

```
    this.auth
      .createAccount({ email: email, password: password })
      .then((res) => {
        window.alert('logged');
        console.log(res);
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        window.alert('wrong bro');
        this.dialog.open(NotificationComponent, {
          data: {
            title: 'Authentication Error',
            error: err['message'],
          },
        });
      });
```

and this is how I call my service,

unfortunately dont know how but first it runs the catch block stating the above error and then block after the dialog is closed.

After this process I can see an account entry in my console.

Since there was not a single account in the console from beginning, why I am getting this error while creating new account.

Comment: Have you tried with different credentials?

Comment: I literally tried random email id